# Update hierarchy after deletion of row

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have a table that contains tree-like data (hierarchic design). Here is a small sample:

```
+----+----------+-----------+-------+----------+---------+
| ID | ParentID | Hierarchy | Order | FullPath | Project |
+----+----------+-----------+-------+----------+---------+
|  1 | null     |         1 |     1 | 1        |       1 |
|  2 | null     |         2 |     2 | 2        |       1 |
|  3 | 1        |       1.1 |     1 | 1-3      |       1 |
|  4 | 1        |       1.2 |     2 | 1-4      |       1 |
|  5 | 4        |     1.2.1 |     1 | 1-4-5    |       1 |
|  6 | 2        |       2.1 |     1 | 2-6      |       1 |
|  7 | null     |         3 |     1 | 1        |       2 |
+----+----------+-----------+-------+----------+---------+
```

`Project` indicates which project owns the hierarchic dataset
`ParentID` is the ID of the parent node, it has a foreign key on `ID`.
`Order` is the rank of the element in one branch. For example, IDs `1, 2 and 7` are on the same node while `3 and 4` are in another.
`FullPath` shows the order using the ID (it's for system use and performance reasons).

`Hierarchy` is the column displayed to the user, which displays the hierarchy to the UI. It auto calculates after every insert, update and delete, and it's the one I'm having issues.

I created a procedure for deletion elements in the table. It receives as input the ID of the element to delete and deletes it, along with it's children if any. Then, it recalculates the `FullPath` and the `Order Column` .That works.

Problems is when I try to update the `Hierarchy` column. I use this procedure:

```
SELECT  T.ID,
        T.ParentID,
        CASE WHEN T.ParentID IS NOT NULL THEN 
            CONCAT(T1.Hierarchy, '.', CAST(T.Order AS NVARCHAR(255))) 
        ELSE 
            CAST(T.Order AS NVARCHAR(255))
        END AS Hierarchy
INTO    #tmp
FROM    t_HierarchyTable T
LEFT JOIN   t_HierarchyTable T1
        ON  T1.ID = T.ParentID
WHERE Project = @Project --Variable to only update the current project for performance
ORDER BY T.FullPath

--Update the table with ID as key on tmp table
```

This fails when I delete items that have lower order than others and they have children.
For example, if I delete the item 3, item 4 `Hierachy` will be corrected (1.1), BUT its child won't (it will stay at 1.2.1, while it should be 1.1.1). I added the order by to make sure parents where updated first, but no change.

What is my error, I really don't know how to fix this.

Comment: It looks like you're _really_ close to using HierarchyID with that `Hierarchy` column. If you commit to it, there is the `GetReparentedValue()` method that you can use along with `IsDescendantOf()` to find all the children of a particular node and then move the entire sub-tree under a new parent.

Comment: I did not know that there were system methods for this. I'll look into the SqlHierachyId type if it can simplify my work. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. The one tip I'd give is use the PK values as the hierarchy path constituents. That is, the hierarchy for your id 5 would be `/1/4/5/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to update the hierarchy with a CTE. Since I have the order, I can append it to `Hierarchy`, based on the previous branch (parent) who is already updated.

```
;WITH CODES(ID, sCode, iLevel) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        T.[ID]                                  AS [ID],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000), T.[Order])       AS [Hierarchy],
        1                                       AS [iLevel]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[data] AS T
    WHERE 
        T.[ParentID] IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        T.[ID]                                      AS [ID],
        P.[Hierarchy] + IIF(RIGHT(P.[Hierarchy], 1) <> '-', '-', '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000), T.[Order])    AS [Hierarchy],
        P.[iLevel] + 1                              AS [iLevel]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[data] AS T
    INNER JOIN CODES AS P ON 
        P.[ID] = T.[ParentID]
    WHERE
        P.[iLevel] < 100
)
SELECT 
    [ID], [Hierarchy], [iLevel]
INTO
    #CODES
FROM 
    CODES
```