# Updating Hierarchical Data in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I’m working with hierarchical data in Entity Framework Core. Each record, or ‘dossier’, has a SectionCode that represents its position in the hierarchy, and a ParentId that links to its parent dossier.

When I delete a dossier, I want to update the SectionCode of all subsequent dossiers at the same hierarchy level, as well as their child dossiers. However, I’m facing an issue where the SectionCode is not being updated correctly for all levels of the hierarchy.
This is my code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Dossier>> DeleteDossier(string sectionCode)
{
    var dossier = await _context.Dossiers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.SectionCode == sectionCode);
    if (dossier == null) { return NotFound(); }

    // Find all child dossiers
    var childDossiers = _context.Dossiers.Where(d => d.SectionCode.StartsWith(sectionCode) && d.Id != dossier.Id).ToList();

    // Delete all child dossiers
    foreach (var child in childDossiers)
    {
        await DeleteDossier(child.SectionCode);
    }

    // Delete parent dossier
    _context.Dossiers.Remove(dossier);

    // Update SectionCode, ParentId and OrderNumber of nodes that follow the deleted one at the same hierarchy level
    var subsequentDossiers = _context.Dossiers.Where(d => d.ParentId == dossier.ParentId && d.OrderNumber > dossier.OrderNumber).ToList();

    // Collect all dossiers that need updating into a list
    List<Dossier> dossiersToUpdate = new List<Dossier>();

    foreach (var subsequentDossier in subsequentDossiers)
    {
        subsequentDossier.OrderNumber--;
        var sectionCodeParts = subsequentDossier.SectionCode.Split('.');
        sectionCodeParts[sectionCodeParts.Length - 1] = subsequentDossier.OrderNumber.ToString();
        subsequentDossier.SectionCode = string.Join('.', sectionCodeParts);

        // Add subsequentDossier to the update list
        dossiersToUpdate.Add(subsequentDossier);
    }

    // Update SectionCode for all dossiers in the list
    foreach (var dossiers in dossiersToUpdate)
    {
        UpdateChildDossiers(dossiers);
    }

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return NoContent();
}

private void UpdateChildDossiers(Dossier parentDossier)
{
    var childDossiers = _context.Dossiers.Where(d => d.ParentId == parentDossier.Id).ToList();
    foreach (var childDossier in childDossiers)
    {
        var childSectionCodeParts = childDossier.SectionCode.Split('.');
        childSectionCodeParts[childSectionCodeParts.Length - 2] = parentDossier.OrderNumber.ToString();
        childDossier.SectionCode = string.Join('.', childSectionCodeParts);

        // Recursive update of SectionCode for child nodes of the current dossier
        UpdateChildDossiers(childDossier);
    }
}
```

The data is updated, as it were, but not at all levels of the hierarchy

JSON before section 2 DELETE:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "parentId": null,
    "orderNumber": 1,
    "sectionCode": "1",
    "name": "string"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "parentId": 1,
    "orderNumber": 1,
    "sectionCode": "1.1",
    "name": "string"
  },
  {
    "id": 43,
    "parentId": null,
    "orderNumber": 2,
    "sectionCode": "2",
    "name": "string"
  },
  {
    "id": 44,
    "parentId": 43,
    "orderNumber": 1,
    "sectionCode": "2.1",
    "name": "string"
  },
  {
    "id": 45,
    "parentId": 43,
    "orderNumber": 2,
    "sectionCode": "2.2",
    "name": "string"
  },
  {
    "id": 46,
    "parentId": null,
    "orderNumber": 3,
    "sectionCode": "3",
    "name": "string"
  },
  {
    "id": 47,
    "parentId": 46,
    "orderNumber": 1,
    "sectionCode": "3.1",
    "name": "string"
  },
  {
    "id": 48,
    "parentId": 46,
    "orderNumber": 2,
    "sectionCode": "3.2",
    "name": "string"
  },
  {
    "id": 49,
    "parentId": 48,
    "orderNumber": 1,
    "sectionCode": "3.2.1",
    "name": "string"
  }
]
```

After DELETE:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "parentId": null,
    "orderNumber": 1,
    "sectionCode": "1",
    "name": "string"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "parentId": 1,
    "orderNumber": 1,
    "sectionCode": "1.1",
    "name": "string"
  },
  {
    "id": 46,
    "parentId": null,
    "orderNumber": 2,
    "sectionCode": "2",
    "name": "string"
  },
  {
    "id": 47,
    "parentId": 46,
    "orderNumber": 1,
    "sectionCode": "2.1",
    "name": "string"
  },
  {
    "id": 48,
    "parentId": 46,
    "orderNumber": 2,
    "sectionCode": "2.2",
    "name": "string"
  },
  {
    "id": 49,
    "parentId": 48,
    "orderNumber": 1,
    "sectionCode": "3.2.1",
    "name": "string"
  }
]
```

as you can see section 3 has not completely updated its number.

Comment: Updating hierarchies after an insert or delete isn't trivial, and probably something best done in the database itself rather than with EF.  The issue is that the "touch surface" can be the majority of a table when you delete a main branch and need to bump a lot of rows forward.  Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62959413/update-hierarchy-after-deletion-of-row